# SQL trigger to cancel the effect of deleting

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to create a trigger named UndeleteU2Track. The objective of this trigger is to cancel the effect of deleting any track from the Track table that associates with an album where the artist is U2. The key is the trigger does not stop the deletion but it cancels its effect by recreating the exact same row or rows of deleted track or tracks. Also, the trigger ignores deletion of track that has no association with U2

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UndeleteU2Track BEFORE DELETE ON Track
BEGIN
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN OLD.TrackID IN (
        SELECT t.TrackID 
        FROM Track AS t, Album AS a 
        WHERE t.AlbumID == a.AlbumID AND a.ArtistID == 
        (SELECT ArtistID From Artist WHERE Name == "U2"))
    THEN
    INSERT INTO Track Values 
        (OLD.TrackID, OLD.Name, OLD.AlbumID, OLD.MediaTypeID, 
            OlD.GenreID, OLD.Composer, OLD.Millisecond, OLD.Byte, OLD.UnitPrice);
END;
END;
```

I got syntax error.

Comment: Huh?  Is this some sort of really weird homework assignment?

Comment: The reactive nature of triggers makes them a maintenance concern at the best of times. This is just begging for trouble. I strongly suggest you rethink your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing or correcting your SQL (because it will require me to create your tables in my DB and I don't have SQL for that), I will give you pointers because I believe your approach is wrong.

1. If you execute this trigger "BEFORE DELETE" and if TrackId is primary or unique key, this insert will fail because remember the record has not yet been deleted.  So it has to be AFTER DELETE.
2. A before delete trigger may be used and if a U2 record (as in your example) exists, a custom exception may be raised to abort the delete operation.

> ```
> SIGNAL SQLSTATE ='45000'
> SET MESSAGE_TEXT ='CANNOT DELETE THIS RECORD'
> ```

3. Better strategy is to check before delete if the record should be deleted.  Triggers are sometimes overlooked by people and if someone new is reviewing the DB design, that person may overlook the logic. Something like this:

E.g.

```
    IF NOT EXISTS
       (  SELECT t.TrackID FROM Track AS t, Album AS a  WHERE t.AlbumID = a.AlbumID AND a.ArtistID IN  
(SELECT ArtistID From Artist WHERE `Name` = 'U2')
   ) THEN 
            DELETE FROM TRACK WHERE TRACKID=p_TrackId;
             END IF;
```

Comment: PS: Code formatting is not working for me today on stackoverflow.

Comment: Code formatting doesn't work after lists. The simplest way I know of to fix it is add another paragraph (as I've done).

Comment: Hi @CraigYoung , thank you for your answer. I'm still getting `Error: near "SELECT": syntax error`

Comment: @kybookie  try       SELECT t.TrackID FROM Track AS t, Album AS a  WHERE t.AlbumID = a.AlbumID AND a.ArtistID IN  (SELECT ArtistID From Artist WHERE `Name` = 'U2')

Comment: This is what I have: `CREATE TRIGGER UndeleteU2Track 
BEFORE DELETE ON Track
 IF NOT EXISTS
       (  SELECT t.TrackID FROM Track AS t, Album AS a  WHERE t.AlbumID = a.AlbumID AND a.ArtistID IN  
(SELECT ArtistID From Artist WHERE 'Name' = 'U2')
   ) THEN 
            DELETE FROM TRACK WHERE TRACKID = p_TrackId;
             END IF;
END;` I'm I missing something?

Comment: @kybookie  Sorry if it was not clear.  This code needs to go to the place where delete is being fired and not in the trigger.  If you want to use a trigger, use BEFORE DELETE trigger and raise an exception to abort deletion.